# Dynamically consuming WCF in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 app and this app needs to consume a WCF service to send/receive data from my server.
I have the service and the app working well in my developer computer, using localhost and VS2013.

Now I installed the WCF service in IIS and the service is working well!

My question is: I want a way to dinamicaly  change the address of my WCF service without the need to recompile the app and deploy it!

I've found this peace of code in another thread at SO that I would like to know if it would work in any address that I change in my app dinamycally:

```
private MyServiceClient GetMyServiceClient(string url)
{
   Uri uri = new Uri(url);
   BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
   EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
   MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
   return client;
}
```

My app will run for now just in intranet enviroment, so I don't need a high security level to access my server, the basic httpbinding it's for now good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at putting your wcf configuration into a configuration file.  See the post here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932(v=vs.110).aspx

Also take a look at this link - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576820/Basic-Step-by-Step-WCF-WebService

It gives an example of consuming a wcf endpoint that is defined in a config file.  It uses a wpf example, but it should be easily adaptable to your scenario.

Comment: But in this scenario as far as I understood is the same that I'm using now, the wcf server settings is stored in app.config and I need to change it manually and re-deploy the app using VS2013 again! If I use the config files like you said, how can I send change this settings in the app deployed on the device ?